How does sample size affect the probability distribution of the maximum of a sample mean
If I take $x$ random samples of size $n$ and then compute their means. How does the distribution of the maximum value of these $x$ means change as $n$ increases?
I've plotted the result and it seems to show something resembling a funnel plot. The variance of the maximum and its mean seem to decrease as the sample size increases and eventually stabilize.
If anyone could explain why this shape develops I'd greatly appreciate it


It presumably depends on the distribution you are originally sampling from.  If it is from a normal distribution then for given $x$, I would expect the amount your blue line is above the original mean would be proportional to about $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, so a slow decline as $n$ increases.  If it from a Cauchy distribution then I would not expect the decline to happen at all - and it might be better to draw the blue line as the median of the maximums rather than the mean.
